# Theme hook suggestions for the breadcrumb block

Tags: 7, blocks, theming

I'm using the Omega theme with the Delta module.
How can I theme the breadcrumb block using block--breadcrumb.tpl.php?
I want to change the output of the block to something similar to the following.

```
<nav id="breadcrumb">
  <ul>
    <li></li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 1):

You should copy `theme_breadcrumb` to your theme's template.php file:

```
function YOURTHEME_breadcrumb($variables) {
  $breadcrumb = $variables['breadcrumb'];
  if (!empty($breadcrumb)) {
      $crumbs = '<nav><ul class="breadcrumbs">'; 
      foreach($breadcrumb as $value) {
           $crumbs .= '<li>'.$value.'</li>';
      }
      $crumbs .= '</ul></nav>';
    }
      return $crumbs;
  }
```

By this function you can set up a `ui li` structure.